# Recursive method with condition

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby 2.0. Here's my code:

```
module Test
  class A
    def initialize(x)
      @x = x
      foo
    end

    def foo
      p @x
      update(@x) # only if it's a Test::C object or called from Test::C
    end
  end
end

module Test
  class B < A
    def foo
      @x += 2
      super
    end
  end
end

module Test
  class C < A
    def foo
      @x += 1
      super
    end
  end
end

def update(x)
  if x > 100
    Test::B.new(x)
  else
    Test::C.new(x)
  end
end

x = 100
update(x)
```

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

**In `Test::A#foo`, `update(@x)` should be called only if it were called from `Test::C#foo` or it's a `Test::C` object.**

The first time `update(x)` is called, `x = 100`, so the operation should `+1` and then move on to `Test::B#foo` once. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is "it" in "...or it's a `Test::C` object"?

Comment: This question is very unclear since you specify `update` at the highest level but then call it inside `Test::A#foo` and you never actually call the `foo` method anywhere so nothing is actually happening here. If `Test::A#foo` should only be called from `Test::C#foo` then that is where you implement it. If `Test::A` does not need to update and `Test::B` does not need to update why would you put the logic at such a high level? Also this does not seem to have anything to do with recursion at all

Answer (score 1):

The parent class should not have to care about subclasses. This design you have here implies it needs to know, which is broken and over-complicates things.

In any case, if you do need to trap certain cases:

```
case (self)
when Test::A, Test::B
  # ... Do stuff
  update(@x)
end
```

If `Test::A` and `Test::B` care about that operation, they should call it when necessary:

```
def foo
  @x += 1
  super
  update(x)
end
```

Comment: I could probably do this `update(@x) if self.is_a?(Test::C)`, but is there a better way to write it? Actually don't need to worry about the value, but my end goal is: everytime `Test::C` is initialized, it should run `foo` based on `Test::C` once, then run it again as `Test::B`.

Comment: While you *can* do that, it doesn't mean you *should*. Generally it's best to put class-specific logic in the subclass and have the parent class unconcerned with those details. Translating your goal to Ruby, that'd imply you do something inside `Test::C#initialize`, for example.